# Can .xsession-errors be cleared while KDE is running?

Tags: linux, xorg, kde, privacy, kubuntu

In general, I like the ability to see the log messages in `.xsession-errors`, and possibly attach them to automated bug reports. But sometimes this file contains sensitive data that I would like to remove or trim, ideally without leaving my current KDE session.

For example, if I used Gwenview to look at a photo folder that didn't quite contain what I expected, I'd like to forget about it, and I'd like my file system to forget about it as well. Unfortunately, the version of Gwenview in Kubuntu 15.10 is quite verbose about what it does...

```
Creating the cache for:  "/mnt/fileserver/shared/user42/pics/SexyDonkey0001.jpg"
Already in database?  true
      First update :  QDateTime("2015-12-15 21:21:35.000 CET Qt::LocalTime")
       Last update :  QDateTime("2015-12-15 21:21:35.000 CET Qt::LocalTime")
After the adjustment
     Current score :  0
      First update :  QDateTime("2015-12-15 21:21:35.000 CET Qt::LocalTime")
       Last update :  QDateTime("2015-12-15 21:21:35.000 CET Qt::LocalTime")
         New score :  0
```

`rm`-ing the file just unlinks it, but X continues to write to it. Part of the file may or may not be nulled out. `> .xsession-errors` didn't have much of an effect either.

Suggestions?

---

**EDIT** in reply to @user55325:
(I don't have the reputation to create comments yet, sorry about this)

I already tried to truncate the file (with `> .xsession-errors`); it doesn't work as long as X has the file handle open:

```
$ ls -l .xsession-errors
-rw------- 1 me me 2.5M Dec 15 23:57 .xsession-errors
$ truncate --size=0 .xsession-errors
$ ls -l .xsession-errors
-rw------- 1 me me 0 Dec 15 23:58 .xsession-errors
$ gwenview tmp/test.png 2>/dev/null
$ ls -l .xsession-errors
-rw------- 1 me me 2.5M Dec 15 23:58 .xsession-errors
```

Comment: Is the data restored or only the EOF? Normally when a program writes past EOF on Unix it autofills with zero (NUL) bytes, sometimes implemented as a 'gap' in a 'sparse' file that doesn't actually use disk space.

Comment: Most of the file was already nulled from my earlier attempt with `rm`, but the end contains more than the log output from gwenview.

Comment: When truncating with `> .xsession-errors` the data is discarded. But the xserver probably does not have the file opened in append mode, so a new write will add bytes to the old size of the file, leaving you with a sparse file. Check with `ls -s` to see how many blocks are actually allocated, you will see it is much less than you expect given the apparent file size in bytes. The begin of the file will show just null bytes which do not take up disk space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`truncate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate) to get rid of the file's contents:

`truncate --size=0 ~/.xsession-errors`

This also allows you to reclaim any space used by the file - occasionally X errors can cause the file size to increase out of control.